# Setting up environment variables for windows using GitBash

Tags: java, jar, environment-variables, classpath, git-bash

I am trying to set up several java jar files and packages as environment variables for a computational linear algebra class.

I am using the GitBash terminal on Windows OS.

I open the file ".bashrc" and use the following string

export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:C:\Users\geniu\testclasspath.jar:.

The address is based on the "copy as address" command for the jar file I wanted to use.

I also tried different ways of acknowledging the root directory including "\c:", "\c\Users..." and starting with "\Users" as the examples on the course website show.

When I use the command:

echo $CLASSPATH.

The GitBash terminal shows no results, and the program provided by the professor used to test environment variables does not work.  I eventually need multiple classpaths, which I believe require a ":" between each file location.

Comment: For git-bash (MSYS), you need to use forward slashes:  /c/Users/geniu/testclasspath.jar

Comment: do I need to get rid of colons after the root directory?

Comment: If you mean remove them from c: or d:, yes.

Answer (score 0):

For git-bash (MSYS), you need to use forward slashes: /c/Users/geniu/testclasspath.jar

```
$ echo $CLASSPATH
/c/bin/

redwa@robert-lg MINGW64 ~
$ export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/c/Users/geniu/testclasspath.jar

redwa@robert-lg MINGW64 ~
$ echo $CLASSPATH
/c/bin:/c/Users/geniu/testclasspath.jar
```